# XCUITest: Failed ( Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) ) when trying click on text field

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, xctestcase

I'm getting this error on the XCUITest when trying click on text field: (i'm using **Xcode Version 9.4.1** )

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

This the unit Test:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textField = app.secureTextFields["pass"]
textField.tap()
```

Comment: it looks like `textField` does not exist. can you `print(textField)` before `textField.tap()` to see if it is not `nil` or it does not crash?

Comment: provide some more code to check outlet of your or the tap() method's code.

Comment: @regina_fallangi the below result displays with me when print(textField)
 ----> "pass" SecureTextField

Comment: On which line is the crash happening?

Comment: thanks @Cristik the issue is happing only on iOS Version 11.1

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, when using the simulator with iOS version **11.1** displays the below issue when using **textField.tap()**

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

this issue is not appear when using the simulator with iOS version **11.4**